# Sample of NServiceBus Pub/Sub over Net TCP WCF?

Tags: wcf, nservicebus, nettcpbinding

Is this possible? trying to look for examples that show a message being published by the server and having multiple clients subscribed to those messages

Comment: The communication between nservicebus endpoints is facilitated by MSMQ. If you want pub sub via wcf, then you'l need to implement your own framework. See [iDesign](http://www.idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11) or Microsoft samples for examples on how to do that.

Comment: thanks @stephenl, we are going to implement via MSMQ.. our WCF project is fairly small right now, and we are contemplating on moving everything to NServiceBus and take WCF out of the picture altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you could probably build a message transport over WCF with the NetTcpBinding, but you really don't want to.  I wouldn't want to try.

It would be very difficult to replicate transactional message sending, store-and-forward, and the receive once and only once semantics that is baked right in to MSMQ.